# Binding not working inside foreach in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have to iterate over a dynamic array and build a form and validate it. I do define the error property but I get an error saying `"object doesn't support property or method 'error'` and this is triggered by the markup, I believe. I have a bunch of other, non array properties that are validated in the same manner no issues, I am only have a binding error problem with the array one.

so in my html I have

```
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: methToChange.nameTranslations">
            <tr>
                <td><div class="method-lb-1"><label data-bind="text:LangName"></label></div></td>
                <td><div class="method-left">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xl" maxlength="40" placeholder="required"
                            onblur="validateNameTranslations()" 
                            data-bind="value:Translation, css: { 'methods-border-error':  $parent.error() }" />
                     </div>
                 </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

in js I have, the below model

nameTranslations is an array of objects {LangName, Translation}

```
methToChange: {
        //many other properties
        nameTranslations: ko.observableArray([])
},
```

And later on I init the value and create the error observable, then update the array

```
init: function() {
  model.methToChange.nameTranslations.error = ko.observable(false);
}

update: function() {
       var model = model.methToChange;

       model.nameTranslations(item.NameTranslations);
},

css: { 'methods-border-error':  $parent.error() }" this part causes an issue and throws an error saying that error property is undefined.
```

The definitions for `nameTranslations` array are placed in the same order as for the other non-array fields, my hunch is that I am not invoking this correctly inside `foreach`.

Comment: My first guess is that `error` doesn't -yet- exist at binding-time. You may need to define `error` as an observable first, and then merely change its value during `init`.

Comment: @Jason, I thought so too but all other variables are defined in the same manner....so why would this be any different? I will try to add to the model and see if that helps before resorting to Jquery validation. This is very elegant but it always takes longer to implement

Comment: The second thing I'm noticing as I look at your code more closely, is that I'm not sure which object `error` is supposed to be on. The binding is to $parent which would put it at the same level as `methToChange`, but your init is placing it 2 levels deeper.

Comment: @Jason, i think you might be correct - is the a way to reference error in the markup? The error is as defined inside init. My understanding was that $parent inside foreach is in my case nameTranslations. And since the error is defined as nameTranslations.error, then $parent.error should work. Am I wrong? Maybe there is no way to refer to it. It's just for css binding, no biggie...but it would be nice if it worked

Comment: If init is correct then I think you can just remove $parent and leave the binding as `'methods-border-error':  error`. The foreach context change already places the context inside the nameTranslations object. $parent would take you back outside of the foreach

Comment: You're creating a new observable error on the nameTranslations observableArray. $parent then references methToChange.
Where do you want the error exactly? On the methToChange, or the nameTranslation itself?

Comment: @Jason and Phil, no go, I tried it error() as well as error. Going back to just using jquery to apply css. Thanks for you help! i already spent half a day on this today and it really shouldn't take up so much time

Comment: I will try one more thing to define the error outside of the nameTranslations, if that does not bind then I am done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I have the basic structure correct, I think the issue is that $parent actually relates to the parent of `methToChange` and not the parent of `nameTranslations`.

```js
var model = {
  methToChange: {
    //many other properties
    nameTranslations: ko.observableArray([{
      LangName: 'Talaxion',
      Translation: 'Klingon',
      NameTranslations: 'something'
    }])
  },

  init: function() {
    model.methToChange.nameTranslations.error = ko.observable(false);
  },

  update: function(item) {
    var model = model.methToChange;

    model.nameTranslations(item.NameTranslations);
  },
  validateNameTranslations: function(item) {
    model.methToChange.nameTranslations.error(true);
    
    return false;
  }
}
model.init();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

```css
.methods-border-error{
border-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: methToChange.nameTranslations">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="method-lb-1"><label data-bind="text:LangName"></label></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="method-left">
          <input type="text" class="input-xl" maxlength="40" placeholder="required" data-bind="value:Translation, css: { 'methods-border-error':  $parent.methToChange.nameTranslations.error }, event: {blur: $parent.validateNameTranslations}" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up defining a var called ntError on the main level and used `$root.ntError()`to call it. Nothing else worked inside the loop